# Showing text on LCD Display with C# UWP and GPIO

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi, uwp, raspberry-pi3, windows-10-iot-core

I'm currently trying to show "Hello World" on 16x2 LCD display which I have already connected to the breadboard, which is connecting to Raspberry Pi with Windows 10 IoT Core. I have searched libraries that might be able to handle. I found [RaspberryPiDotNet Library](https://github.com/cypherkey/RaspberryPi.Net/) but it is not compatible with UWP as it seems.

Is there any libraries or ways to get "Hello World" on my screen?

What I have tried:

- Import the library to the project. It is in .sln format so I tried to make .dll out of it, and it causes incompatibility that one is using .NET Core, while other uses .NET Framework
- Find C# APIs that allows LCD display

Comment: May Help: [Raspberry Pi and Mono – Hello World!](http://logicalgenetics.com/raspberry-pi-and-mono-hello-world/) , [Getting up and running with Mono and Raspberry Pi 3](http://blog.bennymichielsen.be/2016/03/14/getting-up-and-running-with-mono-and-raspberry-pi-3/)

Comment: What kind of your LCD display?

Comment: I have the same issue with my 16x2 LCD display that came in the Adafruit "Companion Parts Pack for Adventures in Raspberry Pi". I still haven't found a library that works for me in UWP.

Comment: @Abdousamad, check out this thread, https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/samples/arduino-wiring/LCDTextDisplay, with code sample https://github.com/ms-iot/samples/tree/develop/ArduinoLibraryLcdDisplay

Comment: @Jackie, thank you for the reply, but what I'm looking for and what Bearfinn is looking for I think is a C# library. The one used in your links is a C++ library. I've tried the library in ChrsitophH answer a while back and I couldn't get it to work, even after triple checking the wiring.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a lot of samples for this topic on the Microsoft Developers page.

[Microsoft projects](https://microsoft.hackster.io/en-US/search?q=LCD)

[Example 1](https://microsoft.hackster.io/en-US/dzerycz/character-lcd-over-i2c-ba8ee9?ref=search&ref_id=LCD&offset=1)
[Example 2](https://microsoft.hackster.io/en-US/rvoltr/basic-lcd-16x2-48482b?ref=search&ref_id=LCD&offset=0)